# How to compare different rows of the same DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to find **a fast method** to compare every DataFrame row with the next `N` without using a "for cycle" (due to time computational problems).

Here an example. My dataframe `df` is:

`index | col 1 | col 2`

`0         c`

`1         a`

`2         b`

`3         b`

`4         c`

`...`

I want to insert `True`/`False` in `col 2` (i-th rows) if, in one of the next N, the `col 1` value is the same as the one in the i-th row.

Here the results for N=3.

`index | col 1 | col 2`

`0         c    False`

`1         a    False`

`2         b    True`

`3         b    False`

`4         c    True`

`5         a    ...`

`6         c`

`...`

NB I've tried to create new columns with `shift` and compare with `.loc`, but with big N I still have computational problems

Comment: I don't understand. You want row 2 in `col 2` to be true because it's 2nd row and `N=2`?

Comment: No. Row 2 is TRUE because we look at the next 3 rows and i find at least one with the same `col 1` value

Answer (score 0):

So, a python equivalent would look something like:  `col2[i] = col1[i] in col1[i+1:i+N+1]` in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Creating new columns with `shift` might not work when N is big, maybe you can try an approach using element-wise comparison with shifted values:

```
N = 10
v = pd.Series(False, index=df.index)
for i in range(1, N):
    v = v | (df['col 1'] == df['col 1'].shift(-i))

df['col 2'] = v
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
N = 2
df["col_2"] = [
    df.loc[i + 1 : i + N, "col_1"].eq(x).any()
    for i, x in enumerate(df["col_1"])
]
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   index col_1  col_2
0      0     c  False
1      1     a  False
2      2     b   True
3      3     b  False
4      4     c  False
```